# How to display individual objects in a column

Tags: r

let's say I have a column named X, and in this column i have 'objects' (what is the right word?) a, b, and c.

X: 
a
a
a
b
b
c
c
c
c
a
a
b
a
c
....

And I want R to tell me that the objects in this column are a, b and c.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `unique(X)` ? ...

Answer (score 0):

unique(matrix_name[column number]) - run this. A built in example in R is the data set mtcars. So, if we wanted to see the individual values possible in column 2, which provides the number of cylinders in each car, we could do this:

unique(mtcars[2]) - the result will grab the first instance of each unique value in column 2 of the data set mtcars, so the result will include the name of the car that was the first instance for each unique cylinder value... so you don't just get 4, 6, and 8 but rather you get...
Mazda RX4 with 6 cyl, Datsun 710 with 4 cyl, and
Hornet Sportabout with 8 cyl.